# Overriding a method when creating a new object

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

I'm using the [Watchdog library](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) to monitor different folders. There are two folders with two different behaviors:

1. In folder `alpha`, when a new file is created, move it to `destination_alpha`.
2. In folder `beta`, when a new file is created, pass it to a method.

Here's the code snippet for the first behavior:

```
import shutil
from watchdog.events import FileSystemHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer

class FolderWatcher(FileSystemEventHandlder):
    '''Overrides the on_created method to take action when a file is created.'''
    def on_created(self, event):
        shutil.move(event.src_path, '/destination_alpha')
event_handler = FolderWatcher()
folder_alpha_observer = Observer()
folder_alpha_observer.schedule(event_handler,'/folder_alpha')
try:
    while True:
    time.sleep(1)
finally: 
    folder_alpha_observer.stop()
    folder_alpha_observer.join()
```

Can I reuse the same class for another `FolderWatcher` object with different behavior in the `on_created` method? Or do I need to create a new `FolderWatcher`-ish class with a different `on_created` method?

```
class SecondFolderWatcher(FileSystemEventHandlder):
    '''Overrides the on_created method to take action when a file is created.'''
    def on_created(self, event):
        imported_method(event.src_path)
second_folder_watcher = SecondFolderWatcher()
folder_beta_observer = Observer()
folder_beta_observer.schedule(second_folder_watcher,'/folder_alpha')
try:
    while True:
    time.sleep(1)
finally: 
    folder_alpha_observer.stop()
    folder_alpha_observer.join()
```

This doesn't seem very elegant, creating a whole new class for every `on_created` action I want to take. But I don't see a better way to do it. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always inject a callback function:

```
class FolderWatcher(FileSystemEventHandlder):
    '''Overrides the on_created method to take action when a file is created.'''
    def __init__(self, on_created_cb):
        super().__init__()
        self._on_created_cb = on_created_cb

    def on_created(self, event):
        self._on_created_cb(event)

event_handler = FolderWatcher(
    lambda event: shutil.move(event.src_path, '/destination_alpha')
)
second_folder_watcher = FolderWatcher(
    lambda event: imported_method(event.src_path)
)
# etc
```

Comment: I knew there was some advanced feature of OOP that would solve the issue. Now I'm off to study callback functions.

Comment: You could extend this to a class that takes a callback for *any* of the five event types as well, and override `dispatch` to call the correct one. (But oh, the boilerplate! It might not be worth it. I was going to write up an answer demonstrating it, but it was too tedious.)

Comment: How can I create a scriptblock for the lambda? In the example above, the lambda is just one command: shutil.move(). If I needed multiple commands there, could I put them all on line? If I wanted to put them into a method, would I put the method inside __main__ or inside the FolderWatcher class?

Comment: You can define any function you like in a `def` statement, as long as it takes an `event` argument, and then pass that function in as the `on_created_cb` argument.  `lambda` is just a convenient way to do it as a one-liner.  Your function *can* be a method of an object (any object) but it doesn't need to be (the lambda isn't, right?).